# Perl can't locate function, but packet was installed

Tags: perl, excel, spreadsheet

I'm using Spreadsheet::WriteExcel packet to create some Excel files.
Everything works fine but when I'm trying to set up column width using:

```
$excel->set_column("A:F",  20);
```

were excel is:

```
my $excel = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('test.xls');
```

I got error:

> Can't locate object method "set_column" via package
>   "Spreadsheet::WriteExcel" at  test.pl line 49.

I don't understand it, because all other functions works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call that method on a worksheet object, not a workbook.